# iText7 Arabic font (RTL language) C#

Tags: c#, fonts, arabic, itext7

I'm using iText7. I need to print Arabic string (direction Right to Left) to the pdf. But arabic string is generated in PDF as left to right format. 
eg. if the arabic string is "abcde" .  It prints as "edcba" 
Here is the code, that I used.

```
void do_something(){
var times = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FONT_TIMES, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
Style arabic = new Style().SetBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
Paragrapg p = new Paragraphh();
p.SetFont(times );
p.AddStyle(arabic );
Text t = new Text("أسبوع");
p.Add(t);
document.Add(p);
}
```

But the arabic text doesn't display as expected. Can anyone please help me, what to do to print arabic strings?

Comment: Did you include the pdfCalligraph DLL? That DLL should be included whenever you need special writing systems. It isn't included by default because the extra processing power needed to examine the content would slow applications down that don't need that extra processing.

Comment: I didn't include pdfCalligraph DLL. Is pdfCalligraph free add on?

Comment: One of the problems we experienced in the past with iText, is that developers didn't (want to) understand the AGPL. iText is free of charge *on condition that* you obey the rules of the AGPL. This means that you aren't allowed to distribute closed source software that depends on iText. To avoid such abuse, we made a couple of add-ons closed source. Which add-ons? Those add-ons of which we know that there's no open source alternative. pdfCalligraph is such an add-on. Hence, due to the ignorance of some, that add-on is closed source for all.